# What Generates the Error?

Tags: errors, preamble

I have been trying to figure out why the following preamble generates the error

```
"\Alpha undefined \renewcommand{\Alpha}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oAlpha$}}}"
```

for hours, but I don't seem to be able to spot it at all, generating me a lot of frustration (the error occurs with several other letters; but not with all of them). **Can anyone spot the cause of the error in the following MWE?**

```
\documentclass{report}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage[sloped]{fourier} % To customise font.

% GREEK ITALIC CAPITAL LETTERS

\let\Alpha\otherAlpha
\let\Beta\otherBeta
\let\Gamma\otherGamma
\let\Delta\otherDelta
\let\Epsilon\otherEpsilon
\let\Theta\otherTheta
\let\Eta\otherEta
\let\Theta\otherTheta
\let\Iota\otherIota
\let\Kappa\otherKappa
\let\Lambda\otherLambda
\let\Mu\otherMu
\let\Nu\otherNu
\let\Chi\otherChi
\let\Omicron\otherOmicron
\let\Pi\otherPi
\let\Rho\otherRho
\let\Sigma\otherSigma
\let\Tau\otherTau
\let\Upsilon\otherUpsilon
\let\Phi\otherPhi
\let\Chi\otherChi
\let\Psi\otherPsi
\let\Omega\otherOmega

\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{\ensuremath{#2}}}

\let\oAlpha\Alpha
\renewcommand{\Alpha}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oAlpha$}}}
\let\oBeta\Beta
\renewcommand{\Beta}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oBeta$}}}
\let\oGamma\Gamma
\renewcommand{\Gamma}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oGamma$}}}
\let\oDelta\Delta
\renewcommand{\Delta}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oDelta$}}}
\let\oEpsilon\Epsilon
\renewcommand{\Epsilon}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oEpsilon$}}}
\let\oTheta\Theta
\renewcommand{\Theta}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oTheta$}}}
\let\oIota\Iota
\renewcommand{\Iota}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oIota$}}}
\let\oKappa\Kappa
\renewcommand{\Kappa}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oKappa$}}}
\let\oLambda\Lambda
\renewcommand{\Lambda}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oLambda$}}}
\let\oMu\Mu
\renewcommand{\Mu}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oMu$}}}
\let\oNu\Nu
\renewcommand{\Nu}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oNu$}}}
\let\oChi\Chi
\renewcommand{\Chi}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oChi$}}}
\let\oOmicron\Omicron
\renewcommand{\Omicron}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oOmicron$}}}
\let\oPi\Pi
\renewcommand{\Pi}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oPi$}}}
\let\oRho\Rho
\renewcommand{\Rho}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oRho$}}}
\let\oSigma\Sigma
\renewcommand{\Sigma}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oSigma$}}}
\let\oUpsilon\Upsilon
\renewcommand{\Upsilon}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oUpsilon$}}}
\let\oPhi\Phi
\renewcommand{\Phi}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oPhi$}}}
\let\oPsi\Psi
\renewcommand{\Psi}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oPsi$}}}
\let\oOmega\Omega
\renewcommand{\Omega}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oOmega$}}}

\begin{document}
WHATEVER.
\end{document}
```

Thank you all in advance for your time and sorry for the rather 'useless' question.

Comment: Please make your code minimal.

Comment: I'll do my best to reduce it; give me some additional time, please.

Comment: You are doing `\let\Alpha\otherAlpha`. Is \otherAlpha defined?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, it is part of `fourier` font package to get slanted Capital Greek letters.

Comment: @TeXnician Now the code is really minimal. To downvoter: why the downvote if now it is a real MWE? Please, explain the reason why; just downvoting does not help much.

Comment: You got the downvote before your last edit. And I didn't downvote, but *really* minimal would have only one letter, not the whole alphabet (assuming the problem applies to all). That said, it doesn't look like `fourier` defines `\otherAlpha`, though it does define `\otheralpha`.

Comment: Oh, and you need the `graphicx` package for `\scalebox`.

Comment: Incidentally, you appear to be leaving off the (re)definition of `\Zeta`. Is this deliberate?

Comment: @TorbjørnT., thanks a lot for the clarifications. As I read it from Fourier package documentation in page 6 (http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/fonts/fourier-GUT/doc/latex/fourier/fourier-doc-en.pdf), Fourier does define `\otherAlpha`, but I may be wrong. I'll add the `graphicx`; I deleted by mistake when trying to make the code minimal.

Comment: @Mico This is not intentional; I just forgot about it (my bad). Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: There is no mention of `\otherAlpha` in the documentation, only `\otheralpha`, and it doesn't show in the list of letters either.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Maybe you are right (I'm relatively new to Latex, slightly more than a year, only); but as a matter of fact, `\otherAlpha` generates no problem. As pointed out in the accepted answer, the crash was generated by a wrong use of `renewcommand` when `\newcommand` had to be used. Thank you all for your fast, precise and useful comments. I swear I'll do my best to provide better MWE next time.

Comment: Yes it does, try `\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[sloped]{fourier} 
\begin{document}
$\otherAlpha$
\end{document}`. I don't know the details here, but if you try to use `\let\somenewmacro\someundefinedmacro` that obviously doesn't cause any errors, but it will only leave `\somenewmacro` undefined as well.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Now, I'd love to remove my comments. You are absolutely right and I was totally wrong. Thank you for pointing it out and helping me see my mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The uppercase-greek-letter commands `\Alpha`, `\Beta`, `\Epsilon`, `\Zeta`, `\Eta`, `\Iota`, `\Kappa`, `\Mu`, `\Nu`, `\Omicron`, `\Rho`, `\Tau`, and `\Chi` are all undefined. Why?! It's because it's much easier (on most keyboards!) to enter these letters as `A`, `B`, `E`, `Z`, ..., `T`, and `X`, respectively.

Because `\Alpha` isn't defined,

```
\renewcommand{\Alpha}{...}
```

is doomed to crash. In those cases, use `\newcommand{\Alpha}{...}`, etc. Do make sure that these definitions are happening in terms of macros that are already defined. For instance, because you have `\let\oAlpha\Alpha` and `\Alpha` isn't (yet) defined, `\oAlpha` isn't defined properly via this `\let` instruction. Hence,

```
\newcommand{\Alpha}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$\oAlpha$}}}
```

is also bound to crash. What you *really* need is

```
\newcommand{\Alpha}{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.3}{$A$}}}
```

and so one for `\Beta`, `\Epsilon`, etc.

Comment: This answer solves the question. Now, there are no errors (before, I was changing renewcommand for newcommand for the wrong letters, and hence the error persisted). It was again my bad. Thus, answer is now accepted. Thanks a lot.